Using greek letters for x-axis labels in ggplot
I want the x-axis labels "beta", "gamma" and "sigma" in the ggplot to be in Greek letters.
library(sensitivity)
library(boot)
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

n <- 100
t <- 1:n 


X <- data.frame(
  beta = runif(n, 0.3, 0.9),
  gamma = runif(n, 0.0714, 0.214),
  sigma = runif(n, 0.125, 0.375)
)


colnames(X) <- c("beta", "gamma", "sigma")
head(X)
tail(X)
View(X)
y <- with(X,  beta/gamma)
x <- pcc(X, y, rank = TRUE, semi = FALSE, nboot = 100)
print(x)

 ggplot(x, aes(x = factor(1:3, labels = c(expression(beta), expression(gamma), expression(sigma))))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(y = y), colour = "red", fill = "blue", size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(linewidth  = 0.4, colour = "grey10"),
        text = element_text(size = 12, family = "calibri"),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
        legend.position = "top",
        strip.text = element_text(size = 12, colour = 'white')) +
  ylab("Sensitivity Index") +
  xlab("") +
  labs(title =  "Sensitivity Analysis")

I have made several attempts but they are not giving the desired output.

You should be passing the expression to the labels argument. The Y axis is not showing up because of the font arguments in the theme for me but this should do the trick!
library(boot)
library(sensitivity)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

x <- pcc(X, y, rank = TRUE, semi = FALSE, nboot = 100)

plot_data = x$X |>  
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = 'parameter',
               values_to = 'value') 


ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = reorder(parameter, -value),
 y = value)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c('beta' = expression(beta),
                              'gamma' = expression(gamma),
                              'sigma' = expression(sigma))) +
  labs(y = 'Sensitivity Index',
 title = 'Sensitivity Analysis', x = NULL) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(linewidth  = 0.4, colour = "grey10"),
        text = element_text(size = 12, family = "calibri"),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
        legend.position = "top",
        strip.text = element_text(size = 12, colour = 'white'))



Created on 2024-06-17 with reprex v2.1.0

In stead of colnames(X) <- c("beta", "gamma", "sigma"), you can either use
colnames(X) <- c("β", "γ", "σ")

or
colnames(X) <- c("\03B2", "\u03B3", "\u030C")


Thanks a lot sir. Will give it a trial
